# In ASP.NET how can I retrieve data from a specific control that is within a DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Within a DataList I have comments retrieved from a database. Each comment set has its own reply textbox along with a submit button to submit the reply. On the button I have an click event along with the commentID as a commandArgument so I can retrieve the comment id in my event. How do i reference the specific comment box to retrieve the text though. My comment container looks something like:

```
<div class="replyContainer">
    <asp:TextBox ID="replyBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("cID") %>'
        onclick="replyPostClick" />
</div>
```

My C# method behind looks something like:

```
protected void replyPostClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btn = sender as ImageButton;
    CommentQueries.addComment(objectID, userID, btn.CommandArgument.ToString(), ?); 
}
```

The question mark would be where I pass in the comment. Is there some way to retrieve the relevant textbox's text somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `DataListItem` from the ImageButton which has been clicked.

The code would be something like;

```
ImageButton img = (ImageButton)sender;
DataListItem item = (DataListItem)img.NamingContainer;

// check that the item is not null
if (item != null)
{        

    //get the index of the Current ImageButton selected
    int itemIndex = item.ItemIndex;
    // find the control and value within the datalist using the itemIndex
    // I don't know the ID of your DataList, so I have just called it DataList1
    var replyText = ((TextBox)this.DataList1.Items[item.ItemIndex].FindControl("replyBox")).Text;

}
```

Once you have the `item` you can can then

Comment: You sir have just empowered a mad man with new found knowledge thank you. You even solved a problem I knew I was going to have to solve later on. Magnificent.